# Why is any() only defined for a numeric and not logical data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators, any

This appears to be quite surprising:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=TRUE, B=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(A=1, B=2)

> any(df1)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

> any(df2)
[1] TRUE
```

This doesn't seem to be a bug because the error correctly states that `any()` will only work in the case where all variables within a `data.frame` are numeric.

But what is the reason for `any()` to work on all numeric variables and not when values are all logical?

Comment: Maybe you should take this to [r-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure when this was changed, but in R version 4.2.3 this works without issues:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=TRUE, B=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(A=1, B=2)

> any(df1)
[1] TRUE

> any(df2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

`any` can work if it is `vector` as the documentation says

> Given a set of logical vectors, is at least one of the values true?

In the OP's post, both examples are not `vector`s.  The first is a data.frame with `logical` columns.  If we go by way to satisfy the documentation i.e create a logical vector, either convert to `matrix` (as a `matrix` is a `vector` anyway with some `dim` attributes)

```
any(as.matrix(df1))
#[1] TRUE
```

Or change it to a `vector` by `unlist`ing the `list` (a `data.frame` is a `list` of `vector`s aka columns of same length)

```
any(unlist(df1))
```

In the second case, there is a warning and it is doing some coercing

```
any(df2)
#[1] TRUE
```

> Warning message: In any(c(1, 2), na.rm = FALSE) :   coercing argument
>   of type 'double' to logical

Comment: This is a fast response, but I don't think it tries to answer the question. The warning and coercing only raises more questions, i.e why does it coerce a numeric `data.frame` to logical, but doesn't work on a logical `data.frame` in the first place.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius Yes, this behavior is, well, illogical.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius I updated the post as both of your `any` examples are not the correct method for `any`.  Some of the behavior could be bug, but it clearly mentioned to pass a vector